# AngularJs, $resource: How to read expanded URL template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Is there a way to read URL template expanded with all the parameters (URL which was really called) after call to server in `AngularJS` `$resource`?

It is for logging purpose when something goes wrong with the call I would like to log the actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish that with an interceptor. This way you dont have to add your logging stuff to all the $resources'.

This goes in your app.js

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('loggingInterceptor', function($q) {
 return {
  // optional method
   'request': function(config) {
     return config;
    },

  // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
    // log your error
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },

  // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
    // do something on success
      return response;
    },

  // optional method
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
    // log your error
       return $q.reject(rejection);
    }};
  });

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('loggingInterceptor');
```

Btw, you can get the url from the 'config object in the request method. Just do a console.log(config) and pick it up from there. I think its config.url

More on interceptors in [AgularJS $http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation under the **Interceptors** topic.

Comment: config object does not contain URL expanded with request parameters.

Comment: You can get the params from `config.params `

Comment: It is not expanded URL (URL actually called by $http), you cannot copy & paste it into browser to debut an issue. Thank you for the answer anyway. It is admirable how your reputation grows.

Comment: Thank you! I can take a look at it in a bit. If you could post a plunker, that would be great